# MaterialDateTimePicker: How to keep datePicker opened after selection?

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using the [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) in my android application. For some raisons, I want to keep the datePicker opened after the user selects a date. The problem is that even if I don't call the `dismiss()` function in the onDateSet, the datePicker is closed.

```
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        String startDate = "You picked the following start date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year;
        Log.d(TAG, startDate);
}
```

How can I keep it opened?

Answer (score 0):

try this use `OnDismissListener` and `OnCancelListener`
Both pickers can be passed a `DialogInterface.OnDismissLisener` or `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` which allows you to run code when either of these events occur.

```
tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
      // show again your datepicker dialog here
    }
});
```

Comment: "show again your datepicker dialog here" it means that its not possible to keep it opened?

Comment: i think yes @Llg

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this function? autoDismiss

```
 /**
 * Set whether the picker should dismiss itself when a day is selected
 *
 * @param autoDismiss true if the dialog should dismiss itself when a day is selected
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void autoDismiss(boolean autoDismiss) {
    mAutoDismiss = autoDismiss;
}
```